# "which ruby" points to a non-existent directory, how do i get it to point to the same directory as "whereis ruby"?

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, terminal, path

I'm using a bash shell in Terminal on my MacBook running 10.21.1

When I type the command `which ruby` I get the result of `/opt/local/bin/ruby`, which no longer exists. My Ruby environment got messed up years ago and now I want to start from scratch, so I deleted the extra version.

However, when I type `whereis ruby` I get the result of `/usr/bin/ruby`, the default directory for Ruby on OSX.

`/opt/local/bin/ruby` is not in `/etc/paths`, but `/usr/bin/ruby` is.

How do I get them to point to the same place? Is it better to just install a version manager and let it do that work for me?

After a lot more poking around, and trying to determine if it was actually something with hash, I don't think it is.

Looking at ~/.bashrc, it has the following line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

And ~/.bashprofile has:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Could that be why `echo $PATH` includes `/opt/local/bin` and is that safe to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be helpful to anyone else, but it turned out I still had MacPorts installed, which was also using that opt/local directory and I had to clean that up to make everything point correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If "which ruby" is returning an obsolete location, that is probably because you have it aliased to **`type`**, and because the information *exists* only in your shell's ***hash***.  You can clear that with

```
hash -r
```

The `whereis` program does not use the hashed information, but mainly relies upon **`$PATH`** (and eliminating the obsolete information, bash will give consistent results).

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't get that to work actually, and I can't figure out how to get a helpful google search. When I just typed `hash` I got `/usr/bin/which` and `/usr/bin/whereis` as my hits, if that's more informative?